# Trouble in Clicking on Log in Google Button of Pop Up Menu Playwright Python

Tags: python, selenium, browser, automation, playwright

[image]

I am having trouble shifting my cursor from back page to front page using python playwright. I already write a script for that which does not seems like work for me as mentioned in the documentation. I have also attached the script below for your ease. Kindly suggest me solution for how I can click on this pop up menu **Log in with Google** Button. Thank you

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import os
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=False)


        
    #Opening a New Page on Browser
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.wait_for_timeout(10000)
    
    
    BASE_URL = r"https://tinder.com"
    page.goto(BASE_URL)

    page.get_by_role("button", name="I accept").click()
    page.get_by_role("link", name="Log in").click()

    page.get_by_role("button", name="Log in with Google").click()
    with page.expect_popup() as popup_info:
        page.get_by_role("button", name="Log in with Google").click()
        
    page1 = popup_info.value

    page.get_by_role("textbox", name="Email or phone").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Playwright **has no** method get_by_role.

Try this:

```
page.locator('link[name="Log in"]').click()
```

You can give the locator method any CSS or Xpath expression.

Comment: playwright had other also  get_by_role method too.